# Help Changing Page Title

Tags: master-page, editing-menu

I am trying to change the page title for a pre-existing page in SharePoint.  I've gone into "Edit" and changed the title from "Travel and Security" to "Immigration, Travel And Security".

However, when I save, the title at the top changes to "Immigration, Travel And Security", but the link on the left remains "Travel and Security".

How do I get the page link on the left to update to the new title?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go into Site Settings and click on either the Quick Launch or Navigation link in the Look and Feel section. From there you'll be able to edit it.